# Parallelism with std::async launch not happening , same thread is executing

Tags: multithreading, c++11, asynchronous

I am trying to exploit the std::async functionality to do parallelism. But if i print the thread id, it's always returning the same value. Semms like it's running this code sequentially. Am i missing something?

Code :

```
int main()
{
    bool check = false;
    auto func = [&](int i) 
                          { 
                            std::cout<<"  i : "<<i<<"  thread_id : "<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<" ";
                            check = true;
                          }

    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        std::async(std::async::launch, func, j);
    }

    std::cout<<" check : "<<check<<" ";

    return 0;
}
```

Result :

```
i : 0  thread_id : 47263726
i : 1  thread_id : 47263726
i : 2  thread_id : 47263726
i : 3  thread_id : 47263726
i : 4  thread_id : 47263726
.
.
.
```

Comment: Your code doesn't take any time, so why would it need to run in multiple threads?  It can run faster by not spawning threads.  Perhaps you should test with a workload that actually consumes CPU time.

Comment: I agree, but this is a sample i have shown, can't paste actual code,  i am doing some heavy operations in "func". My intension with this sample is, if it's correct or i missed something conceptually.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I don't think it matters. [The doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) says "*If the async flag is set (i.e. (policy & std::launch::async) != 0), then async executes the callable object f on a new thread of execution, as if spawned by std::thread(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...),*". I understand that this flag should force spawning new threads (even if it doesn't make sense) and this should be reflected in thread id.

Answer (score 4):

As per note [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async):

> If the std::future obtained from std::async is not moved from or bound to a reference, the destructor of the std::future will block at the end of the full expression until the asynchronous operation completes, essentially making code [...] synchronous

This is exactly your case. You need to take care of the `async` return.

```
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>

int main()
{
    auto func = [](int i) { 
      std::cout<<"  i : "<<i<<"  thread_id : "<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<"\n";
    };

    using Handle = std::future<void>; // pretty hard to be figured out automatically 
                                      // from lambda, but your function "returns" void
    std::vector<Handle> handles;
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        handles.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, func, j));
        //result of std::async is implicitly moved onto the vector
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
  i : 6  thread_id : 47713265002240
  i : 7  thread_id : 47713267103488
  i : 8  thread_id : 47713269204736
  i : 9  thread_id : 47713271305984
  i : 5  thread_id : 47713262900992
  i : 4  thread_id : 47713260799744
  i : 3  thread_id : 47713258698496
  i : 2  thread_id : 47713256597248
  i : 1  thread_id : 47713254496000
  i : 0  thread_id : 47713252394752
```

Comment: this is so helpful. i was just completely confused. it just kept running synchronously.

Answer (score 2):

`std::async` returns a temporary future object, which is then immediately destroyed. [`std::future` destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future) is allowed to block in this specific case, waiting for the asynchronous operation to complete. This is likely what you observe - `func` calls do run sequentially, and just happen to get assigned to the same worker thread.